# Enforcing Single Record In Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to use MongoDB as a simple caching mechanism to store a handful of records.  These records come from an external service and rarely change (though they have the possibliity to change every once in a while).

Is there a way of enforcing a single record on a collection?  Since the ID's could potentially change, I don't want to set the _id as the API's ID, and enforcing uniqueness on the API ID doesn't handle the eventual ID changes.

I could potentially handle this myself by upserting the record and dropping all records that don't contain the updated ID, however I was hoping for some sort of functionality inside MongoDB that handles this.

I'd like to avoid adding a dedicated caching solution for now, though it seems like this would be a better solution than using MongoDB for this use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about it, I've opted to handle this a bit differently.

I'm going to put each unique record that I want into a single collection (which is only a handful).  I'm going to add a "group" field that I'll use to determine what type of record I'm storing.  I'm also going to require it for all records, require it to be unique, as well as add validation to ensure that it is of what group that I want it in.

Kind of confusing, here's a bit of my Schema to show what I'm talking about:

```
isValidSet = function(val) {
  [ 'branch', 'department', 'division', 'group' ].indexOf( input || '' ) > -1
};

cacheSchema = new Schema({
  code : { type : String, required : true },
  name : { type : String, required : true },
  shortName : { type : String, required : true },
  group : { 
    type : String, 
    required : true, 
    unique : true, 
    validate : [ isValidGLSet, 'Invalid GL group!' ] }
});
```